# Is that possible to get the reference to an array from the referent of its element?

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have a php function, in which the 1st parameter is a reference to an array and the 2nd parameter is one of its keys,

```
function fun(&$a, $k) {
......
}
```

I want to modify the function so that I just need to pass one parameter `$a[$k]`. Inside the function , `$a` can be extracted from `$a[$k]` and then I can call `array_search($a[$k], $a)` to get `$k`. Is that possible in PHP?

```
function fun(&$ak) {
// $ak is from $a[$k] 
// a php utility to extract $a from $ak? ...
$k = array_search($ak, $a);
}
```

Comment: `$a[$k]` would give you the value located at index `$k` in array `$a`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I question is it possible get $k from a reference to $a[$k]. In order to do that, the first step, I think, is to get $a itself from $a[$k]. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Reference does not contain any information about the key of the element or the whole array.

Comment: I've no idea why, but this is funky.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Maybe because you had too much Champagne?

Comment: @kaiser Haha I wish! I meant I've no idea why one is reduced to doing that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, there's no way to "extract" that information, because that information doesn't exist in the scope of your function.

**Long answer:**

As people have pointed out in the comments, you simply cannot do this. If you have a function like this:

```
function fun(&$foo) {
    ...
}
```

there is no information passed to that function about where `$foo` came from. It could be a standalone variable, an array element (`$bar[1]`), an object property (`$baz->bingo`), or anything else (think `SomeClass::$bar->baz[$bingo->boingo]`). There's no way to tell.

To verify this, try `var_dump($ak);` in your function; it won't contain any information about what array or object it's in (or its array index or property name). It's just like any other variable.